# Mercurial hglock extension not working with central repo

Tags: mercurial

Has anyone used the newer hglock extension?  I am having trouble getting it to work with a remote (central) repository.  Hglock says it is not a local.  One thing I have not is install hglocks on the central repository server.

So my question is: How do you really use this extension?

I do the init-locks and the lock tracking file is created in my local clone of the repo and not up on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I have a potential fix in [Issue #11](https://bitbucket.org/lantiq/hglock/issue/11/hglock-not-compatible-with-newest-hg) but I haven't tested it with earlier versions of Mercurial.

By returning a peer rather than a repo there can be other consequences - for example it broke cloning a local repo (which I've also got a fix for in the issue). There might be other problems caused by this.